# Remove double pricing options with variable product in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have used the code snippet below to get 2 types of prices but it ruins everything when I  add variable pricing.

How do I keep the above pricing to be shown but remove the chaos of pricing with the drop-down menu?

Ideally, I would like it to show the two pricing options and then when you choose one of the options in the dropdown menu I would like to show the pricing again of that option.

```
function edit_price_display($price, $instance) {
    global $product;

    if(is_singular('product')) {
        $price = $product->price;
        $price_incl_tax = $price + round($price * ( 25 / 100 ), 2);
        $price_incl_tax = number_format($price_incl_tax, 2, ",", ".");
        $price = number_format($price, 2, ",", ".");
        $display_price = '<span class="price">';
        $display_price .= '<span class="amount">' . $price .'<small class="woocommerce-price-suffix"> kr (exkl.moms) </small></span>';
        $display_price .= '<br>';
        $display_price .= '<span class="amount"> (' . $price_incl_tax .'<small class="woocommerce-price-suffix">  kr inkl.moms </small></span>)';
        $display_price .= '</span>';
        echo $display_price;
    } else {
        echo $price;    
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'edit_price_display', 10, 2);
```